# Comma between proper noun and day name

Tags: grammaticality, commas, style-manuals

In [this recent CNN article](https://www.cnn.com/2019/07/23/asia/south-korea-russia-military-intl-hnk/index.html), I found the following sentence:

> It was one of two incidents involving South Korea, Tuesday.

It seems the comma is intentionally being used to separate the two proper nouns, possibly as a replacement for eliding the word "on," in order to make the sentence easier to read.

Is this use of a comma recognized or advised in any well-known style guide or grammatical authority? I could not find it when I searched.

Comment: That sentence no longer appears in the article, but another does: "After Moscow released its initial statement, Japan confirmed it had also scrambled fighter jets in response to the Russian incursion Tuesday." However, it doesn't include a comma before Tuesday, probably because of the first clause. This doesn't necessarily invalidate the question.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know in news APPs, article titles are usually shortened by eliminating "the on for"and punctuations and thus grammatically wrong.